# Trouble creating objects for class in windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have a class which is given below,

```
public class TryDataContext : DataContext
{
    public Table<Data> Datas
    {
        get
        {
            return this.GetTable<Data>();
        }
    }

    public TryDataContext(string connectionString) : base (connectionString)
    {
    }

}
```

And my app.xaml.cs page is,

```
public void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        using (TryDataContext Empdb = new TryDataContext(strConnectionString))
        {
            if (Empdb.DatabaseExists() == false)
            {
                Empdb.CreateDatabase();
                MessageBox.Show("Database Created Successfully!!!");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Database already exists!!!");
            }
        }
    }
```

Now when i compile the project i get a error stating that,

```
Error   1   The type or namespace name 'TryDataContext' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference)
```

What should i do get out of this issue??
FYI : class TryDataContext is in another file named *TryDataContext.cs*.

Comment: Do you have the correct using statement? Right click the class and hit 'Resolve' if it appears. Failing that, do you have the right references for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

neither namespace of both files are not same.

```
namespace ApplicationNamespace
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
    }
}
```

and TryDataContext.cs should have the same namespace otherwise include that namespace where

and there can be a syntax error. please check that.